# How do I log out when using identity server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Please see the code vlow, which is taken from my Startup.cs in an MVC app

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddCustomMvc(Configuration)
                .AddHttpClientServices(Configuration);

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; 
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "mvc2";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.Scope.Add("MyAPI1");
                    options.Scope.Add("MyAPI2");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                });

        }
```

The authentication and authorisation is working correctly in MyAPI1 and myAPI2, however I cannot logout.  I have tried this:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
```

and this:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

The user is not logged out.  How does the user log out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code to some controller to trigger the sign-out:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
}
```

This will clear the local cookie and then redirect to IdentityServer. IdentityServer will clear its cookies and then give the user a link to return back to the MVC application. Also remember to set `PostLogoutRedirectUris` in client configuration in IDS .

Comment: Are you able to have a look at my other Identity Server question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165224/do-i-have-to-login-to-each-web-application-when-using-identity-server