# Do I have to login to each web application when using Identity Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

Say I have a setup like this:

```
MVCApp1
MVCApp2
Identity Server
```

Therefore there are three projects inside my solution.  Identity Server is now working for all of them.  However, I am finding that I have to login to each one individually.  Is that correct? i.e. if I login to MVCApp1, then does that mean I should also be implicitly logged in to MVCApp2?

Say I wanted to login to all three web apps, then would I have to browse to each web app and login or should I only have to do this once (I thought this is what single sign on was for).

Here is some code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                    options.Authority = identityUrl;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "mvc2";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.Scope.Add("API1");
                    options.Scope.Add("API2");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                });
```

Comment: The idea is that you sign in to Identity Server, which remembers you (either session-based or persistent). You log in with MVCApp1, which gets you to log in to Identity Server. When you proceed to log in with MVCApp2, Identity Server already has you authenticated and so just issues a new token for MVCApp2. Both MVCApp1 and MVCApp2 have a *different* authentication token, but you've only had to log in to Identity Server once.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, I browse to MVCApp1 and it prompts me to login.  Then I immediately browse to MVCApp2 (whilst still logged in to MVCApp1) and it prompts me to login again.  Is that not right?

Comment: If MVCApp1 redirects you to Identity Server to login and then MVCApp2 redirects you to Identity Server to login, I'd expect you to be already logged in to Identity Server on that MVCApp2 redirect and so I wouldn't expect you to be prompted for credentials again. Not every setup is the same, so that's not black and white, but it is the general idea of SSO as I understand it.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, it appears to work if I open a new window inside the same browser.  However, if I open the two apps using two instances of the browser then I have to login twice.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you have a "remember me" option in your Identity Server setup? If so, check it and see if that changes things.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, this only appears to happen when using IE.  Firefox and Chrome work as expected.  Is there an IE setting somewhere?

Comment: My guess is that the auth is being stored in a session, which doesn't track across multiple instances of IE.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, please see the code in my question.  Is there a problem with it? Am I not using cookies? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193480/discussion-between-kirk-larkin-and-w0051977).

Answer (score 0):

SSO is designed to handle this case, and no, you shouldn't need to login to each application individually.

If a user is not logged in, you should redirect them to the login page, when they can authenticate with the Identity Server. Once authenticated, the user should be able to access (without login) to both applications MVCApp1 and MVCApp2.

I would recommend storing your JWT's in a cookie, which can then be shared by your applications IF they live under the same domain. Then when any of your applications require authorization, get the JWT from the cookie in the request header and use that for authentications.

Comment: It appears to work if I open a new window inside the same browser. However, if I open the two apps using two instances of the browser then I have to login twice. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sort of...as long as you are in the same browser, you shouldn't need to login again.

Comment: What if you are opening two separate instances of the same browser?

Comment: Should still work fine, but it really depends on your setup. I can't give you a definitive answer without taking a detailed look.

Comment: Could you give ma an indication where to look?

Comment: It also depends on the browser. How are you persisting your sessions? Using cookies or using ASP.NET sessions?

Comment: this only appears to happen when using IE.  Firefox and Chrome work as expected.  Is there an IE setting somewhere? I was not the down voter.

Comment: I'm not sure, IE is very old and no longer supported by Microsoft, so it may be that it isn't possible in IE. Take a look at [this](https://help.useresponse.com/topic/sso-internet-explorer-not-allowing-cookie) and see if it helps.

Comment: this at least answers the simple question in the title, so why downvoted? global SSO for all the ie instances (within a machine, office, city, world) is a little bit different question. but, yes, it would be nice to mention persistent cookie as Kirk Larkin did in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165224/do-i-have-to-login-to-each-web-application-when-using-identity-server#comment98966361_56165224)